# gcc: lack of warning about order of initialization in constructors

Tags: c++, gcc, initialization, initializer-list

Should gcc to warn about the order of initialization of member variables `a` and `b` in class C? Basically object b is initialized and it's constructor invoked before object A. This means that `b` uses an uninitialized `a`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    private:
        int x;
    public:
        A() : x(10) { cout << __func__ << endl; }
        friend class B;
};

class B
{
    public:
        B(const A& a) { cout << "B: a.x = " << a.x << endl; }
};

class C
{
    private:
        //Note that because b is declared before a it is initialized before a
        //which means b's constructor is executed before a.
        B b;
        A a;

    public:
        C() : b(a) { cout << __func__ << endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    C c;
}
```

Output from gcc:

```
$ g++ -Wall -c ConsInit.cpp 
$
```

Comment: you can tell it to warn you. The flag is -Wreorder and it's turned on with -Wall.

Comment: you should make sure that you compile with `-Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic-errors`. the code will not compile cause gcc will warn you that you are using a uninitialized

Comment: @bamboon: Are you sure? Code compiles fine here.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to help at least on my system... `g++ const_order.cpp -g  -Wall  -Wextra -pedantic-errors -o const_order`
`const_order.cpp:32:5: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Wunused-parameter]`
`const_order.cpp:32:5: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’ [-Wunused-parameter]`

Comment: It looks like your *order* of initialization is fine.  It's just that you are *not* initializing one of your members and then using it.

Comment: I don't get a warning from either gcc or clang on highest warning levels, which is a little odd. You should file bugs with respective trackers.

Comment: @The code compiles fine. I'm interested in whether gcc should warn about the order of initialization in the constructore. I don't care about turning warnings into errors via -Werror. It's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @pmr yeah that's what I'm thinking....it's either a bug or a feature to be added....

Comment: @sashang As I mentioned above, I think your issue is slightly different than order of initialization.

Comment: which gcc versions are you using? It won't compile with 4.6.3(given -Werror, warning with -W)

Comment: Actually, according the spec (c++11, could be rephrased since c++03) this example is perfectly legal and well defined "non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition
(again regardless of the order of the mem-initializers)." (12.6.2/10)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order for this to be an order of initialization issue, you need to actually attempt to initialize the subobjects in the wrong order:

```
public:
    C() : a(), b(a) { cout << __func__ << endl; } 
          ^^^ this is attempted initialization out of order
```

as written, the only violation is binding a reference (the argument of `B::B(const A&)`) to an object (`C::a`) before its lifetime begins, and that's a very questionable violation, since taking a pointer to `a` would actually be legal, under $3.8[basic.life]/5 (and dereferencing it still before a's initialization would be UB)

Comment: I think you are correct.  As you mentioned, technically, it doesn't have anything to do with order of initialization.